# Laravel Cashier incrementQuantity() tidy invoicing

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

Has anybody here dealt with incrementing subscriptions for "admin" users? Also, how do you handle invoicing and first/second-month charges in a neat manner?
I have a use case where users can sign up other subscribers and pay for these subscriptions from their card on file. The "admin" user signs up for the first subscription, and I keep incrementing the original sub every time a new sub is added.

When I send these through Cashier, the user only seems to get charged once, and then the second, third, etc., the first-month cost gets added onto the next month's invoice, and a new line item of unused time every time the admin user adds a new sub. So I first do:

```
$request->user()->newSubscription()->create();
```

Then I do:

```
$request->user()->subscription()->incrementQuantity();
```

The user only gets charged one monthly charge at `newSubscription()->create(),` And the next month's invoice has the following math.
(# of Subscriptions x Monthly Charge) - (Monthly Charge)
And the invoice has a ton of line items saying "Unused Time ..." which looks OK if that admin user only has one or two additions to their subscription but gets messy real quick beyond that. This seems super unprofessional and annoying to explain to the admin users. How do you/would you guys go about making this smoother? I understand that the invoicing for the incrementQuantity() method is enforced by the Stripe API, but it doesn't make sense to have so many prorating adjustments in a first invoice.

Answer (score 1):

What is your goal/desired behavior here? Laravel cashier does allow you to change how you want the prorations to behave. By default prorations will be created and pulled into the next invoice, but you can also choose to disable prorations entirely or create prorations and have them immediately invoiced so that the difference is price is paid for immediately.

If you don't want any prorations generated at all when you update the quantity of a Subscription you can use `noProrate()` (see [laravel's docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/billing#prorations)). Disabling prorations entirely may not be what you want though, since it won't allow you to charge a customer for the difference in price when they update mid-cycle. As an example, if you start off with a `quantity: 1` Subscription they'll be charge for just 1 unit at the start of the month. If prorations are turned off and you update to `quantity: 5`, the customer won't have to pay for the new price until the subscription is renewed. If this is still what you want to do, you'd use it like this: `$request->user()->subscription()->noProrate()-> incrementQuantity()`.

Another option would be to keep generating prorations, but have them immediately invoiced so that they aren't reflected in the renewal invoice at the end of the month. This will result in the customer being invoiced more often, but would solve your issue where the renewal invoice looks cluttered because of all the prorations. You would get this behavior by using `alwaysInvoice()` like this: `$request->user()->subscription()->alwaysInvoice()-> incrementQuantity()`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do want to do prorations but not one charge at a time. I think the thing to do really would be to wait until the next day then charge all prorations at the same time, maybe? It also isn't great to invoice the customer separately for each added subscription. noProrate() doesn't work because then I have to forego the prorated income. alwaysInvoice() is an interesting option but does not seem to be covered in laravel docs. Do you have any resources that detail how that works?

Comment: I don't think they have any specific documentation on `alwaysInvoice()`, but you can see where they defined it here: https://github.com/laravel/cashier-stripe/blob/9661eade4ae42fb0b0b7b351d2d1dc5f10cedb78/src/Concerns/Prorates.php#L43

I'd just suggest trying it out to verify it behaves as you expect